# Why is destructor not called here

Tags: c++

Consider the following code

```
vector<myCustomType> v;
for (int i = 0; i != 5; i++)
{
   v.push_back( myCustomType () );
}
```

I've been reading books which say that destructors are called when an object falls out of scope and to use shared_pointer or other memory tricks to keep the object from being destroyed.

As such, I'd expect the following code to crash the program:

```
v[0]. someMemberFunc ();
```

However, this does not happen. In fact, the object hasn't been destroyed. Why is this?

Thanks!

Comment: `vector` contains copies of what was `push_back`ed so it doesn't matter what happened to the original. And even *if* `v[0]` was a destroyed object, calling a member of an invalid object doesn't necessarily crash the program. It's undefined behavior and anything can happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{
   v.push_back( myCustomType () );
}
```

Here you're placing an object into your vector. The vector is the owner of that object (the object is stored in the vector), so the scope on the object now matches the scope on the vector.

Consider instead:

```
std::vector<CustomType*> v; //store pointers
for (int i = 0; i != 5; i++)
{
   CustomType ct = myCustomType(); // Get a CustomType object
   v.push_back(&ct);
}
```

In this case, like you expected, trying to run `v[0]->someMemberFunc();` will be Undefined Behavior (read: Very Bad). Since the vector isn't actually storing the object, only the address of an object, there's no guarantee that what it's pointing to exists. And since the scope of `ct` is just in that `for`, it *doesn't* exist outside of the loop!

Note here that the difference is in ownership and where and how the object is being stored.

Answer (score 3):

`v` has not fallen out of scope, and retains its 5 `myCustomType` objects.  So accessing one of them and calling a member function on it is perfectly fine.